# how to select characters after first 20 characters from field mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, phpmyadmin

```
 select address (first 20 character) as Address1 , 
        address (characters after first 20 if less then 20 then NULL) as Address2
 from customer
```

How do I select string after 20 characters?

Comment: I think you may be misusing your database. These two fields should be in separate columns so you'll never have to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Probably substring function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: I'm transferring values from one table to another where address field has limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get characters after the first 20 characters (note that if there are not twenty characters, the function will return an empty string):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Some Random Address That is Longer than 20 characters' FROM 20);
```

Now if you need address 2 to be NULL, you check character length first:

```
SELECT if(char_length(address) > 20, SUBSTRING(address FROM 20), NULL);
```

To get the first 20 characters, you can use the substring function like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Some Random Address', 1, 20);
```

Now the final query could look like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(address, 1, 20) as Address1, 
    IF(CHAR_LENGTH(address) > 20, SUBSTRING(address FROM 20), NULL) as Address2
FROM customer
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(address, 1, 20) AS Address1, 
       SUBSTRING(address FROM 20) AS Address2
FROM   customer
```