# Shorten displayed strings that are too long to fit in the returned table

Tags: mysql, cmd

[image]

It's a mild annoyance when long strings (in particular the comment fields in tables) from select queries break the printed table's layout and readability.
Is there a way, perhaps a setting somewhere or script that could be imported, to shorten displayed strings that extend beyond the intended field width (without changing database data of course)?

Comment: Right Click on title bar->Options -> Increase width

Comment: something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431466/how-to-select-characters-after-first-20-characters-from-field-mysql ?

Comment: @lad2025 This doesn't help with very long strings. I'm looking for a way to shorten the strings (for example "This is a shortened c[...]"), not resize the window only to compensate for certain strings

Comment: @Kevin It's more work than i'd want to do to add that for every single query :s

Comment: you should use an sql-browser instead of command line. most slq-browser support the feature you want.